# EF4 Linq - Get top items using criteria from related tables

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

I have 3 tables that I need to include in a linq query in EF4. Am also using dbcontext generator to generate poco classes.  The linq query is querying poco objects.

Hopefully the below explains how tables are related in the underlying database clearly.

OrderDetails > - 1 Books 1 - < BookCategories

As you can see 1 book can have many categories and one book can appear on many orders.

I am trying to get top selling books in a specific category.

So far I have managed to get top selling books overall as below but I cannot seem to extend this to include a book category as criteria in the where clause

```
var topSellingBooks = (from p in this.context.OrderDetails
                        where p.IssueId == issueId && p.PublicationId != "4TC" 
                        group p by p.BookId
                        into bookGroup
                        select new 
                            { 
                                BookNo = bookGroup.Key, 
                                BookCount = bookGroup.Sum(q => q.Quantity) 
                            }).OrderByDescending(q => q.BookCount)
                              .Take(noOfBooks);
```

Using navigation properties, I expected that I could add

```
&& p.Books.BookCategories.CategoryId_FK=="MyCatId"
```

to my where criteria above but this does not seem to be possible.  I cannot access the properties of BookCategories by using the above.

Is this enough info to see what is going on. Anyone got any pointers?

Thanks

Wing

Comment: When you say you "cannot access the properties of BookCategories", what do you mean? Do you get a null reference? An empty collection? What sql is being generated by EF?  (`string sql = topSellingBooks.ToString();`)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a problem with loading strategy.
You need to [Include](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738708.aspx) related objects in your query.

[Read](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx) what are eagerly and lazy loading, you will find lots of examples on this page like:

```
var blogs = context.Blogs
                   .Include(b => b.Posts.Select(p => p.Comments))
                   .ToList();
```

Comment: I don't think you don't need to use include if you have correctly set up lazy loading do you? Is lazy loading enabled? Is the BookCategories property marked virtual?

Comment: Perhaps I have not explained the table relations properly.  Please see revised introduction.  I am also using the dbcontext generator for poco classes.

Comment: @wingyip: Did you try to include `Books` in a similar way as my example and link?

Comment: Yes but no joy. Also, the syntax in the brackets that you used above for the Include is not recognised in my version of EF.